# Memo Field being Truncated in Report Print Preview or when Printed

Tags: ms-access-2010

Ok, I've seen several posts regarding a Memo field being truncated when linked to a query with the DISTINCT attribute.  However, I have a simple report with a memo field that ***successfully grows*** as it needs to and looks fine in **Report View**.  However, in **Print Preview** or when I actually **Print** the report, the memo field gets truncated.  Happens at different character counts.  One record has as much as 772 characters allowed in the memo field, but the remaining 15 aren't. :-\

There is no query involved with this report.  Simply placed the fields on the report and chose Print Preview.

I do have it set to CAN GROW = YES and I'm displaying in RICH TEXT. No Grouping. No Sorting. No nothing.  Two fields, a DATE field, and the Memo field.

Thoughts?

Comment: There is now an entry regarding this bug on the Access uservoice forum. [Please go there and vote](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop/suggestions/13478700-stop-randomly-omitting-text-in-reports) if you suffer from this bug and want to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known bug. It's based on the font and printer. [Another user claimed that switching to Arial fixed the problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-2010-truncation-of-calibri-rich-text-in/8b6242b3-4a8b-4553-969c-42b0ca709849). His issue was with the **Calibri** font, while mine was with the **Tahoma** font.

My experience was that it depended on the printer as well, as my client would get this bug with one printer, but not another, using the same computer.

Switching to the **Arial** font worked for both of us. Except for the testing already mentioned here, there's no list that I can find of which fonts are buggy and which ones work.